# How to Sendgrid Bulk Mail in php?

Tags: php, sendgrid

Hi while sendgrid has limitation like 1000 mails per request how to send over 20k mails ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split your 20k emails up into batches of 1,000 and loop through the batches sending them 1,000 at a time to the API.